# Convert summation with filter to List Comprehension

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension

I'm trying for educational purposes to convert the following code to list comprehension :

```
total = 0
for c in some_list:     
  if c == 'US':
     total += 1
```

I've tried some variations with sum() or the following code which returns false results :

```
 counter = [ c for c in some_list if c=='US']
```

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension at all; `total = some_list.count("US")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to build a list; just use a generator expression and `sum()`:

```
total = sum(1 for c in some_list if c == 'US')
```

You are not summing `c`, you are summing `1` integers.

Alternatively, have the `list` object do the counting for you:

```
total = some_list.count('US')
```

The latter is much faster; the looping and comparisons are then done entirely in C code:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> some_list = [random.choice(['US', 'United Kingdom', 'The Netherlands', 'Norway']) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(1 for c in some_list if c == 'US')", globals={'some_list': some_list}, number=100000)
3.54722355294507
>>> timeit.timeit("some_list.count('US')", globals={'some_list': some_list}, number=100000)
1.0752556619700044
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot guys from stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

try this snippet, hope this helps

```
total = sum(1 for c in some_list if c == 'US')
```

Comment: try this snippet, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
values=['us', 'uk', 'us', 'au', 'us', 'uk', 'uk', 'us']
count = sum(1 for c in values if c=='us')
```